# Design Patterns: multiple swing interfaces listen for thread variable

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, design-patterns, synchronization

I have one big doubt on which design pattern to adopt to obtain the following:

I have a class A which cannot be static which has a running thread which updates a variable a1;

Multiple swing classes (B, C, D) have to update a JLabel b1, c1, d1 with the current value of the variable A.a1.

Because A cannot be static B, C, D cannot do something like like b1.setText(A.getInstance().getA1());

Also creating a new instance of A each time doesn't make sense because A has a specific role and cannot be created each time.

Because A has a thread which updates a1 variable there's also a synchronization problem I think between A,B,C,D sharing this variable for read write.

I thought of Observer pattern but still it requires each B,C,D to register with A and it doesn't solve the synchronization issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decouple the existence of A from B, C, and D, then you need to create a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object which will act as the middleman. This object will know how to reach the instance of A, and make ad-hoc responses when it is not available.

To make the synchronization less a problem, I suggest using a message queue holding the successive changes of the `a1` value. the proxy will poll this queue and update the swing class accordingly. In fact, the proxy may implement the `Observer` pattern for that purpose. The thread working on A will have to post the updates to the message queue. By turning this into a one to one producer consumer setup, you can minimize latency, by using the appropriate queuing, like [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

The `Proxy` doesn't even have to run the update on the swing components for each values in the queue, but just on the latest (throwing away all the intermediate ones).

Update: The [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class seems to be a good candidate for that purpose.

Comment: +1 `SwingWorker` may suitable in this context, as `process()` runs on the EDT and sees a `List<V>` in `publish()` order.